# How to setup AForgeNetUnity for use in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, aforge

I'm wondering what I need to do to be able to use the code here https://github.com/kereyroper/AForgeNetUnity with Unity3d c# scripts.  Specifically I'm after the FourierTransform in Math.

I've tried adding assembly reference in mono develop, and looked around at other options, but to be honest I'm a bit lost!

Answer (score 0):

to add any .net assembly to your unity project, you have to copy it to your Assets/Libraries folder in your unity editor.

then go to:

edit / project settings / player / other settings / optimization / api compatibility level

and set it to: .NET 2.0

EDIT: i checked your link, it looks like you can also simply just copy paste all the code to your Assets folder in unity editor